# Execute awk output exactly inside of executed script

Tags: bash, awk, associative-array

There is some similar topics, but this is slightly different.

---

I have database with names of scripts and parameters `a`. When I execute:

```
sqlite3 log/log.db "select name, a from result" | awk -F '|' '{printf("a[%s]=%s;\n",$1,$2);}'
```

I see:

```
a[inc.bash]=4.23198234894777e-06;
a[inc.c]=3.53343440279423e-10;
```

---

In  my bash script I would like to use an associative array.

---

When I execute this code (coding by hand value of `a[inc.bash]`):

```
declare -A a
a[inc.bash]=4.23198234894777e-06;
echo ${a[inc.bash]}
```

It works correctly and print

```
4.23198234894777e-06
```

---

But I do not know, how to use output of first presented command with awk to assign values of key of associative array `a` declared in my script.

I want to execute code that is printed by awk inside of my script, but when I use something like `$()` or ``` `` ```, it prints a error like this:

code:

```
declare -A a
$(sqlite3 log/log.db "select name, a from result" | awk -F '|' '{printf("a[%s]=%s;\n",$1,$2);}')
echo ${a[inc.bash]}
```

output:

```
a[inc.bash]=4.23198234894777e-06; not found command
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell Bash to interpret your output as commands, you can use process substitution and the `source` command:

```
declare -A a
source <(sqlite3 log/log.db "select name, a from result" |
         awk -F '|' '{printf("a[%s]=%s;\n",$1,$2);}')
echo ${a[inc.bash]}
```

The `<()` construct (process substitution) can be treated like a file, and `source` (or the equivalent `.`) runs the commands in its argument without creating a subshell, making the resulting `a` array accessible in the current shell.

A simplified example to demonstrate, as I don't have your database:

```
$ declare -A a
$ source <(echo 'a[inc.bash]=value')
$ echo "${a[inc.bash]}"
value
```

This all being said, this is about as dangerous as using `eval`: whatever the output of your sqlite/awk script, it will be executed!

Comment: Wow amazing answer. Thanks, everything works. I'll mention you on my blog. Thank you again!